# Wordpress: $wpdb_prepare warning when running $wpdb->delete

Tags: wordpress

I get the following deprecated warning:

Notice: wpdb::prepare was called incorrectly. The query argument of wpdb::prepare() must have a placeholder. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.9.)

It's triggered by this:

```
$wpdb->delete( 'table',array('user_id' => $user_id),array( '%d' ) );
```

I have defined:

```
global $wpdb;
```

This is an exact copy of the [wordpress codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#DELETE_Rows).

What's wrong?

EDIT: The warning only appears in the "Log Deprecated Notice" plugin report, not in my apache log.

Comment: You're _sure_ that's the line that's triggering the warning?  It looks fine.  What version of WordPress are you using?  I just tested with version 4.4.4 and I can't reproduce the error.

Comment: @Hobo: yes, absolutely sure. There are a dozen nearly identical lines in the same file and each is creating a warning (not actually an error). That said, the warning does not appear in my apache log, but only in the "Wordpress Log Deprecated Notices" plugin, so I am suspecting this might be a reporting issue with this plugin more than a real "error".

Comment: Ok; weird.  If you really want to get rid of the warning, you could try replacing it with the equivalent (untested, of the top of my head) `$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("DELETE FROM table WHERE user_id = %d", $user_id));`.  But I'd check with the plugin developers to see if they can explain (and correct, assuming it's in the plugin) the cause.

Comment: That `$wpdb->query()` call might behave differently if `$user_id` isn't set, by the way, but I assume you're checking for that before deletion